# Error: private method `gsub' called for nil:NilClass with pik install ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, jruby, pik

On Windows 7 machine, I have installed jruby 1.6.7 and then installed pik with 'gem install pik'. I then ran pik_install C:\bin which installed pik properly. I can run "pik ls" command properly.

`C:\Users\nir>pik ls
* 167: jruby 1.6.7 (ruby-1.8.7-p357) (2012-02-22 3e82bc8) (Java HotSpot(TM)...`

My PATH is :-
`C:\Users\nir>echo %PATH%`
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin; C:\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\jruby-1.6.7\bin;C:\cygwin\bin;`

However, when I run "pik install ruby 1.9.3" command, I get the following error :-
`C:\Users\nir>pik install ruby 1.9.3`

There was an error:

```
 Error: private method 'gsub' called for nil:NilClass

 in: pik/commands/install_command.rb:24:in `execute'
 in: pik_runner:33`
```

--- The pik version that got installed was 0.2.8. And I have disabled the firewall settings.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved. It was related to firewall settings.

I earlier did this settings in .gemrc file to include:-

gem: --http-proxy=http://ourproxyserveraddress.com:8080

However, it did not work. The below settings fixed the issue :-

1) Control Panel\System and Security\System(My Computer\system properties) -> Advanced System Settings.

2) Create a System environment variable HTTP_PROXY containing the IP address of proxy server and the port number. You will find the information about the proxy server in browser settings - Tools -> Connection -> LAN Settings -> Proxy server